# Attribute error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'array'

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following serie `history_data_price`:

```
483    6528.3
484    6528.3
485    6528.3
486    6528.3
487    6528.3
488    6528.3
489    6528.3
490    6528.3
491    6528.3
492    6528.3
493    6528.3
494    6528.3
495    6528.3
496    6528.3
497    6528.3
498    6528.3
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

Which I created using the following line of code:

`history_data_price = pd.Series(data_linear['price'].iloc[500-H-1:500-1].astype('float'))`

I would like to transform it into an array (not a numpy array), I do the following:
`history_data_price.array`,
but then I have the title error message, any idea why? thanks!

Comment: Please show your full python code, or at least a snippet relevant to this question

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? It looks like `.array` i[s only available](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.array.html) in `0.24.0`+. You might try [to_numpy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.0rc1/api/generated/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html) instead